# Difference between writing compressed file

Tags: c, file, compression, zlib

I am using zlib library to compress my files for my project. I have a compressed file content having 204 chars length. when I tried to write the files in 2 different ways I am getting different chars length as the contents in the file.

When I used ,

```
FILE* dest = fopen("D:\File.gz", "w"); to open the destination file
```

and writes using

```
int count = fwrite(buffer, 1, size, dest);
```

The final file content length becomes 205.

When I used,

```
FILE * dest = stdout; and 
int count = fwrite(buffer, 1, size, dest);
```

I got the correct file size as 204.

Why I am getting 2 different behaviours? When using the first method, the file created is not able to decompress, and shows invalid zip file.

Comment: You should use `fopen("D:\File.gz", "wb");` in order to avoid newline-translation on Windows.

Comment: Thanks!. I tried, but still getting the same issue. File size is 205 bytes

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right file?  `D:\File.gz` doesn't actually have a backslash in it... you need `D:\\File.gz` for that, so it'll write in the current directory on D: which may not be the root directory.  If you have an old copy of the file there - before you used "wb" - you might be mistaking it for newer output.  I suggest you check the creation timestamp, and/or delete it and recreate it.

Comment: Yes. I verified. In my actual code I used, "D:\\File.gz" . But still getting the size as 205. When I opened the gz file in notepad++, it shows the file ending are in mac format. Is there any dependency with this.

Comment: Thanks !!! it worked when I tried with a sample code. Seems like some minor issues with my original code. Anyway I will fix it. Thank you for your support.

Comment: You need to close this question, otherwise people see it is as unanswered and waste time trying to help you.

Comment: Please close this question, it's stand in "unanswered"...